# Add to Cart with Ajax loading entire page

Tags: expresso-store, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#considerthis').click(function() {
            var url = $(this.form).attr('action');
            var data = $(this.form).serialize();
            $.post(url, data, function() {
                $('#ycgroup').load('/shop/_cart');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

With this script its accessing url of `GET http://localhost/shop/_cart 404 (Not Found)` error.

by changing `load('./shop/_cart')` like this updating entire page.

anyway inputs an what i am missing here...

Thanks,

sus

Comment: I've tried to clean up the formatting on your question, but it's still unclear what you're asking. Can you try to be more explicit (e.g. what happens when you visit `/shop/_cart` directly in your browser?). You can indent code blocks with 4 spaces (markdown formatting).

Comment: Getting this below output rendered:                      Your Consideration details:
2 × Samsung Galaxy Leo T36Y676 Rs470.00
Total Rs470.00
Checkout

Comment: But my url is like this - http://localhost/susduslocal/home.php/shop/_cart